# Generate wadl from existing CXF rest service

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I have working JAX-RS service implemented with CXF. How can I generate wadl? Or is there something like with jersey  http://path.to.your/restapp/application.wadl out there already? is there a maven plugin just like for wsdl, java to wsdl? I've searched for answers couldn't find.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of CXF, just hit the service with a ?_wadl parameter.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of possible ways to generate WADL using CXF:

1. You can sent REST call (using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), for example) to the base
   REST URL and it will automatically create WADL for all services
   available from there. It can help to structure REST API. For
   example:

   - http://app.com/purchase/?_wadl - create WADL for purchase API
   - http://app.com/profile/?_wadl - create WADL for user profile API
2. CXF 3.0.0 and 2.7.11 introduce java2wadl plugin for generating WADL at the build time. Details clould be found [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-java2wadlMavenplugin).
3. All available feature of CXF regarding WADL are located [in CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html).

After WADL has been generated it would be nice to transform XML to more readable form. One of the solutions that I found was XSL usage to generate HTML. I have used XSL from [github project](https://github.com/ipcsystems/wadl-stylesheet). Steps to link XSL to XML and generate pretty HTML report:

1. Download wadl.xsl;
2. Copy wadl.xsl to the folder that contains wadl.xml file that was generated by CXF;
3. Add required header to wadl.xml to the very beginning of the file:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

   `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wadl.xsl"?>`
4. Replace in wadl.xml generated `<application ...>` header using 
   `<wadl:application xmlns:wadl="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02 wadl.xsd ">`
5. Add to every tag 'wadl' namespace. For example:

   `<resource>` -> `<wadl:resource>`

   `</resource>` -> `</wadl:resource>`
6. Open wadl.xml using IE
7. You will get something like this (example_wadl.xml from [github project](https://github.com/ipcsystems/wadl-stylesheet)):
   [image: HTML page generated from WADL file]